# Perform Aggregation on MultiIndex Pandas Series

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I would like to perform an aggregation on a multi-index pandas series that looks like so:

```
revenue = 
date        person       shift      
2017-10-19  Adams        A           298.70
            Smith        B           593.46
                         B_Overtime  77.71
2017-10-20  Conner       A           473.08
            Adams        B           441.35
            Smith        C           392.97
2017-10-21  Adams        A           374.79
            Smith        B           169.02
            Conner       C           124.63
```

Where the series is for revenue by date, person and shift. I would like to find the mean of revenue by person and shift, then revenue mean by shift. If I do something like revenue.mean() it just gives me one number since it is a series and can't us groupy again. I looked at unstacking the Series but that seems to make things worse, since I have a bunch of 0's. Which I suppose are ok,since they won't contribute to a mean value. I am stuck on this one.

Answer (score 2):

You can use groupby on a multiindex using levels, say

```
df.groupby(level = [1,2]).mean()
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `Series.mean(level=[...])`:

```
In [13]: s.mean(level=['person','shift'])
Out[13]:
person  shift
Adams   A             336.745
Smith   B             381.240
        B_Overtime     77.710
Conner  A             473.080
Adams   B             441.350
Smith   C             392.970
Conner  C             124.630
Name: val, dtype: float64
```

Comment: This is better than using groupby :)

Comment: @Vaishali, it's just a little bit shorter... ;-)